# Mystery "TypeError: navWrap.offset() is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, undefined

I am completely riddled by this issue, does anyone have a clue what the issue might be?

The code I want to add in my custom js file (in Wordpress) is:

```
var navWrap = jQuery('#sidebarnavWrap'),
    nav = jQuery('#sidebarnav'),
    startPosition = navWrap.offset().top,
    stopPosition = jQuery('#footer-three').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();

jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
//stick nav to top of page
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop()

  if (y > startPosition) {
      nav.addClass('sticky');
      if (y > stopPosition) {
          nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
      } else {
          nav.css('top', 0);
      }
  } else {
    nav.removeClass('sticky');
} 
});
```

This code works perfectly in the jsfiddle. Yet when used on my WordPress site, the console mentions "**TypeError: navWrap.offset(...) is undefined**"

http://jsfiddle.net/ykto7uu9/42/

Do any of you Pro's know what could cause this? 
Thank you so much.

*Extra info: My custom js file already contains a very simple working jQuery code to show/hide text (no conflicts) and I enqueued the script in functions.php using:*

```
function my_javascripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'js.custom', '/wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/js/js.custom.js', array() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_javascripts', 1000 );
```

Comment: I can only guess that the element may not yet be there, can you try putting everything inside a $(function() {});

Comment: Thank you for your time and the suggestion @carloliwanag, but that didn't work. (Already tried that one too) :) Nathan's answer below fixed it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading your JS in the head of the page and you're not waiting for the ready callback. At the time the code fires there is no `sidebarnavWrap` element.

Wrap your entire JS code block in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // CODE HERE

});
```

I'd also recommend a couple of adjustments to your enqueue script call.

1. You're using jQuery so define it as a dependency
2. Move the script to the footer

Updated version:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'js.custom', '/wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/js/js.custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and wonderful reply @Nathan Dawson! Updating the enqueue script call with yours fixed the issue. Thanks again for your time, have a great day.